# numeric cycles in shell

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, cycle

what is the name and syntax of the construction ((..)) in example below?

```
for ((i=1;i<10;i++)) do echo $i; done
```

it has strange variable i
where are other constructions for numeric cycling in shells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In section §3.2.4.2 of the 'Bash Reference Manual' (4.0), the '`((...))`' notation is classified as as an arithmetic expression.  It is closely related to the '`$((...))`' notation described in §3.5.5 as Arithmetic Expansion.  And §3.2.4.1 'Looping Constructs' says:

> An alternate form of the `for` command is also supported:

```
    for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do commands ; done
```

> First, the arithmetic expression expr1 is evaluated according to the rules described
>   below (see Section 6.5 [Shell Arithmetic], page 78). The arithmetic
>   expression expr2 is then evaluated repeatedly until it evaluates to zero. Each
>   time expr2 evaluates to a non-zero value, commands are executed and the arithmetic
>   expression expr3 is evaluated. If any expression is omitted, it behaves as
>   if it evaluates to 1. The return value is the exit status of the last command in
>   list that is executed, or false if any of the expressions is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide's section on Loops](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html) for more examples of looping constructs besides the [C-style for loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html#LOOPCSTYLE) you've listed.

Try also:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done # range argument
1
2
3
4
5
$ for i in `seq 1 5`; do echo $i; done # iterate over seq command
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash(1)` man page, **SHELL GRAMMAR** section, **Compound Commands** subsection. The other choices for numeric loops are `while` and `until` with a manual increment.